# fetch request stuck in pending

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, fetch

I'm working on an application using nodejs, mysql and express currently and I have run into an issue with fetching data from my database.

I have a POST form in the client side for booking and I want to implement a feature for the client to only be able to see non-booked times for the date which they have selected. But the problem is that once they select a date the request gets stuck in pending.

ps. this is a school project so i'm very new to nodejs and programming any help would be greatly appreciated

Heres my router.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const pool = require('../config/database.js')

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home.ejs');
});

router.get('/book', function(req, res){
  res.render('book.ejs')
});

router.get('/book/:date', function(req, res) {
  const date = req.params.date;
  console.log('Start of route handler');

  // Fetch all bookings for the given date
  pool.query('SELECT time FROM bookings WHERE date = ?', [date], function(err, bookings) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something went wrong on the server' });
    }

    console.log('SQL query success');

    // Get all available times for the given date
    try {
      const availableTimes = getAvailableTimes(date, bookings);
      console.log('Successfully retrieved available times');
      res.json(availableTimes);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something went wrong on the server' });
    }
  });
});

// Function to get all available times for a given date
function getAvailableTimes(date, bookings) {
  const allTimes = ['09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00'];
  const bookedTimes = bookings.map(function(booking) {
    return booking.time;
  });
  const availableTimes = allTimes.filter(function(time) {
    return !bookedTimes.includes(time);
  });
  return availableTimes;
}

module.exports = router;
```

client-side file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include("./partial/head.ejs"); -%>

  <body>
    <%- include("./partial/header.ejs"); -%>
      <h1 id="bookHeader">Book an Appointment</h1>
      <form method="post" action="/Bokning" class="bookForm">
        <div class="bookFirstForm">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
        
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required />
        
        <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required />
        </div>
        <div class="bookSecondForm">
        <label for="tjänst">Tjänst:</label>
       <select name="tjänst" id="tjänst">
        <option value="Klippning">Klippning</option>
        <option value="Skägg">Skägg</option>
        <option value="Behandling">Behandling</option>
       </select>

        <label for="barber">barber:</label>
        <select name="barber" id="barber">
          <option value="Mushtaq">Mushtaq</option>
          <option value="Viggo">Viggo</option>
          <option value="Kacper">Kacper</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="bookThirdForm">
        <label for="date">Datum:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" required />
        <label for="time">Tid:</label>
        <select id="time" name="time">
       
        </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Boka Nu!</button>
      </form>

      <%- include("./partial/footer.ejs"); -%>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        const dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
        const timeInput = document.getElementById('time');

// Listen for changes to the date input
dateInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Get the selected date
  const selectedDate = this.value;

  // Make an API call to the server to fetch the booked times for the selected date
  fetch(`/book/${selectedDate}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(availableTimes => {
      // Clear the time input
      timeInput.innerHTML = '';

      // Populate the time input with the available times
      availableTimes.forEach(function(time) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = time;
        option.textContent = time;
        timeInput.appendChild(option);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
});
      </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

I have tried putting console logs in my code but I get nothing in response

Comment: Do you catch any error ?

Comment: What do you get if you console log the `availableTimes` constant in your route ?

Comment: Please share your browser + serveur debug (catch your asynchronous query in your browser debug and check answer status, look at your node serveur logs or nginx if you have one)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the `async` and `await` in your code

```
router.get('/book/:date', async function(req, res) { // MAKE async CALLBACK
  const date = req.params.date;
  console.log('Start of route handler');

  // Fetch all bookings for the given date
  pool.query('SELECT time FROM bookings WHERE date = ?', [date], async function(err, bookings) { // MAKE async CALLBACK
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something went wrong on the server' });
    }

    console.log('SQL query success');

    // Get all available times for the given date
    try {
      const availableTimes = await getAvailableTimes(date, bookings);
      console.log('Successfully retrieved available times');
      res.json(availableTimes);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something went wrong on the server' });
    }
  });
});
```

// Function to get all available times for a given date

```
async function getAvailableTimes(date, bookings) {
  const allTimes = ['09:00:00', '10:00:00', '11:00:00', '12:00:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '15:00:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '18:00:00'];
  const bookedTimes = bookings.map(function(booking) {
    return booking.time;
  });
  const availableTimes = allTimes.filter(function(time) {
    return !bookedTimes.includes(time);
  });
  return availableTimes;
}
```